# Can you set architecture specific Build Settings in an .xcconfig file in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: xcode, xcconfig

I want to set Build Settings that are specific to each architecture (armv6 vs armv7). This is easy enough to do in the Xcode GUI, but I try to put all project configuration in .xcconfig files. Is it possible to replicate the following configuration (Thumb enabled for armv7, but not armv6 architectures) using .xcconfig files?

[image: GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT Settings in Xcode]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

```
SETTING_NAME[arch=arch_name] = some_value
```

It's hard to find documentation on this. Apparently it was in the [Xcode 3.0 release notes](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/259426-xcode-3-0-release-note-3-of-4.html), but good luck finding those in Apple's current docs.

To solve your particular problem:

```
GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT[arch=armv6] = NO
GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT[arch=armv7] = YES
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I edited your answer to add the actual setting that sets the configuration I was asking for.

Comment: Note that you can find that answer yourself by selecting the row that you want the build setting for, and hitting `⌘-C` to copy the setting.  You can then paste it into your xcconfig file as text.